# How to replace sling:resourceType value in bulk using query or script

Tags: aem, sling

How to replace `sling:resourceType` value in bulk using Query and Scipt.

For example I want to change `sling:resourceType` value 
from `app/component/linkButton` to `app/component/content/linkbutton1`.

The component is being used on 20 pages, and I want change it using query rather than manually on each page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ACS AEM Tools](http://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-tools/) open source project which includes [AEM Fiddle](http://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-tools/features/aem-fiddle.html). AEM Fiddle allows you to run scripts directly on the AEM instance without have to build.

If you use AEM Fiddle, navigate to `http://localhost:4502/miscadmin#/etc/acs-tools/aem-fiddle`, click the plus sign in the top right and select `.java`. Insert this code and run. Make sure you update the query's path.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.jcr.query.Query;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.ModifiableValueMap;
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource;
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.ResourceResolver;
import org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingAllMethodsServlet;

public class fiddle extends SlingAllMethodsServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        ResourceResolver resolver = null;

        out.println("starting...");

        try {
            resolver = request.getResourceResolver();

            if (resolver != null) {
                Iterator<Resource> resources = resolver.findResources("/jcr:root/content/mysite//*[@sling:resourceType='app/component/linkButton']", Query.XPATH);

                while (resources.hasNext()) {
                    Resource resource = resources.next();
                    ModifiableValueMap properties = resource.adaptTo(ModifiableValueMap.class);
                    properties.put("sling:resourceType", "app/component/linkButton1");
                    resolver.commit();
                    out.println(resource.getPath());
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            e.printStackTrace(out);
        } finally {
            if (resolver != null && resolver.isLive()) {
                resolver.close();
                resolver = null;
            }
        }

        out.println("...finished");
    }
}
```

If you'd rather use JSP as you've stated, the code is the same:

```
<%@include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp"%><%
%><%@page session="false" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" 
pageEncoding="UTF-8"
import="org.apache.sling.api.resource.*,
java.util.*,
javax.jcr.*,
com.day.cq.search.*,
com.day.cq.wcm.api.*,
com.day.cq.dam.api.*,
javax.jcr.query.Query,
org.apache.sling.api.resource.ModifiableValueMap"%><%

    Iterator<Resource> resources = resourceResolver.findResources("/jcr:root/content/mysite//*[@sling:resourceType='app/component/linkButton']", Query.XPATH);

    while (resources.hasNext()) {
        Resource current = resources.next();
        ModifiableValueMap props = current.adaptTo(ModifiableValueMap.class);
        props.put("sling:resourceType", "app/component/linkButton1");
        resourceResolver.commit();
%>
    <%=current.getPath()%>
<%
    }
%>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, I ran the code in fiddle. but I'm getting this error.                                                                                                  Compilation errors in /apps/acs-tools/components/aemfiddle/fiddle/fiddle.java: Line 1, column 0 : The declared package "" does not match the expected package "apps.acs_002dtools.components.aemfiddle.fiddle"

Cannot serve request to /etc/acs-tools/aem-fiddle/_jcr_content.run.html on this server

ApacheSling/2.4 (jetty/9.2.9.v20150224, Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_66, Mac OS X 10.11.4 x86_64)

Comment: can I do similar code in JSP? I'm doing this first time.

Comment: Make sure you leave the first line that AEM Fiddle writes. It will look something like this: `package apps.acs_002dtools.components.aemfiddle.fiddle;`

Comment: Thank you so much, It is working now.  would you have example using jsp for the same please.?

Comment: Updated to include a JSP version.

Comment: If I helped you out, please remember to upvote and accept my answer.

Answer (score 7):

the best choice for the purpose is [groovy console](https://github.com/Citytechinc/cq-groovy-console) .

Bellow script which do the job:

```
import javax.jcr.Node

getNode('/content/').recurse { resourceNode ->
    if (resourceNode.hasProperty('sling:resourceType')) {
        final def resourceType = resourceNode.getProperty('sling:resourceType').string
        if (resourceType.equals('OLD_RESOURCE_TYPE')) {
            println "changing " + resourceNode.path
            resourceNode.setProperty('sling:resourceType', 'NEW_RESOURCE_TYPE')
            resourceNode.save();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another dirty method, but worked for me. :)

1. Package the path and download the zip file.
2. Extract to a folder.
3. Based on your operating system,

   - If using Windows, use Notepad++ to find an replace in all files    under directory with your search pattern.
   - If linux, use find or sed commands to replace all occurrences    inside a director

Comment: The accepted answer and groovy console answer are much cleaner and less hacked up solution. I wouldn't recommend your approach over them as XML files are very fragile and can be easily broken. Any debugging during import of such broken packages will be overly complex.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Only if I am pressed with time, will follow this. Also, if I have to remove some protected properties like mixintypes in bulk, will do this.

Answer (score 0):

How about `AEM ACS TOOLS`?

It is bulk updating tool for `sling:resourceType` or `cq:Template`.

[Click here for the article on `Getting Started`](https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-tools/features/csv-resource-type-updater/index.html)

[Click here for the Github Repo](https://github.com/Adobe-Consulting-Services/acs-aem-commons)

Good Luck...

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a look at sling pipes.

https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/sling-pipes.html

this is the perfect solution for your problem